# How to manually create a select field from a ModelForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-models

I have a `ModelForm` where one of the field (named `creator`) is a `ForeignKey`, so for `{{ form.creator }}` Django renders the `<select>` tag like this:

```
<select id="id_approver" name="approver">
    <option selected="selected" value="">---------</option>
    <option value="1">hobbes3</option>
    <option value="2">tareqmd</option>
    <option value="3">bob</option>
    <option value="4">sam</option>
    <option value="5">jane</option>
</select>
```

But I want to add a `onchange` event attribute so I can use AJAX later to do something else. I also want to change `---------` to say something else and display the approvers' full name, not their username.

So is it possible to get a list of possible approvers and generate my own select options? Kind of like

```
<select id="id_approver" name="approver" onchange="some_ajax_function()">
    <option select="selected" value="0">Choose a user</option>
{% for approver in form.approver.all %} <!-- This won't work -->
    <option value="{{ approver.pk }}">{{ approver.get_full_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

And I'm also thinking most of the list of approvers get too large (like over 50), then I'll eventually want some sort of a searchable auto-complete field for the approver. So then I'll definitely need to write my own HTML.

In case anyone needs it, my `ModelForm` looks like this:

```
class OrderCreateForm( ModelForm ) :
    class Meta :
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'creator',
            'approver',
            'work_type',
            'comment',
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ModelChoiceField documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) explains how to do this.

To change the empty label:

```
empty_label

    By default the <select> widget used by ModelChoiceField
    will have an empty choice at the top of the list. You can change the text
    of this label (which is "---------" by default) with the empty_label
    attribute, or you can disable the empty label entirely by setting
    empty_label to None:

    # A custom empty label
    field1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=..., empty_label="(Nothing)")

    # No empty label
    field2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=..., empty_label=None)
```

As for your second query, it is also explained the in docs:

```
The __unicode__ method of the model will be called to generate string
representations of the objects for use in the field's choices;
to provide customized representations, subclass ModelChoiceField and override
label_from_instance. This method will receive a model object, and should return
a string suitable for representing it. For example:

class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "My Object #%i" % obj.id
```

Finally, to pass some custom ajax, use the [`attrs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) argument for the select widget (which is what is used in the ModelForm field).

In the end, you should have something like this:

```
creator = MyCustomField(queryset=...,
                        empty_label="Please select",
                        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange':'some_ajax_function()'})
```

Comment: So for your `creator` example above, I'll have to remove `creator` from `fields` in `OrderCreateForm` and add your line of code for `creator = MyCustomField(...)`? Or do I keep `creator` as part of the list in `fields` (under `class Meta`)?

Comment: You should remove it since you are rendering it with a custom field.

Comment: I ended up hardcoding the `<select>` and `<option>` tag for `creator` in the template since I needed more complicated `creator` list that depended on the `User`. Thanks for the response, nonetheless! I still learned something :-).

Comment: You could have created a custom renderer (with a custom widget), and it would have taken care of the HTML as well.

Comment: Well the `creator` list is dynamic depending on the `user.profile.user_type`. I understand I can change the `creator` list with `queryset` in `MyCustomField`, but unless I can pass an optional variable `user_type` to `class OrderCreateForm( ModelForm )`, then I'll have to create like 5 different (but mostly same) `OrderCreateForm`.

Comment: You should open a new question, because what you ask is completely doable but the comments system isn't for long discussions.

Comment: After some tinkering and `pdb` debugging, I found out that you actually need to do `fields['creator'] = MyCustomField(...)`. Otherwise you can't use `{{ form.creator }}` in the template. Just to let you know! :-)